# Do we really need Rouché’s theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis

When I first heared about Rouché’s theorem, I said to myself: "Wow, this is a great result since it gives us a method to determine approximately where the zeros of a polynomial are located". However, the other day it struck me that maybe we don't need any deep, advanced theorem like that to determine such a thing. Wouldn't it work to just use the reverse triangle inequality (which belongs to elementary math)?

I will try to explain my idea by solving a particular problem.

In Wikipedia, Rouché’s theorem is used to prove that the polynomial $z^5+3z^3+7$ has exactly five zeros in the disc $|z|<2.$ As expected, the argument is that $|z^5|$ dominates $|3z^3+7|$ on the circle $|z|=2$, which implies that $z^5+3z^3+7$ and $z^5$ have the same number of zeros inside it.

Can we prove the same thing by applying the reverse triangle inequality? Yes, I think so. To begin with, that inequality gives us $|z^5+3z^3+7|\ge|z|^5-3|z|^3-7.$

Now let's consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}, f(r)=r^5-3r^3-7.$ What about its derivative? Well $f'(r)=5r^4-9r^2=r^2(5r^2-9)$, which is positive if $r>2.$ Hence $f$ is strictly increasing in the interval $[2,\infty).$ In fact $f$ is positive there since $f(2)=1.$

It follows that there can be no zero of the polynomial $z^5+3z^3+7$ with absolute value greater than or equal to 2. However, the fundamental theorem of algebra in combination with the factor theorem tells us that the number of zeros of that polynomial is five, so we can conclude that it has five zeros in the disc $|z|<2,$ as desired.

Do we really need Rouché’s theorem? That’s what I want to ask now. It seems like we don’t really need it, at least not to determine the approximate location of the zeros of a polynomial. If I’m not mistaken, we can get the job done with such a simple tool as the reverse triangle inequality.

Comment: Rouche' works for non-polynomials.

Comment: Sometimes it’s not as easy to apply the triangle inequality. For instance (found from a MO question in a certain context): how many roots of $x^9+5x+3$ lie in the unit disk? There’s at least one (a negative real number), so you can’t rule them out by the triangle inequality. But not all of them do (consider the product). So how many?

Comment: Even for polynomials Rouche (which of course is very general and applies to all analytic functions) can be subtle as noted above by @Aphelli  We always have the Cauchy bound for the roots - the one noted in the OP, so if $P(z)=\sum a_n z^n$ that is the highest positive root $r_P$ of $|a_n|r^n-\sum_{ k \le n-1}|a_k|r^k$ and by default all roots satisfy $|z| \le r_P$, but otherwise things can be quite tricky; also Rouche applies to other domains like say a half or quarter disc where absolute value considerations are generally less useful as arguments enter the picture too

Comment: @FShrike Maybe we can use the reverse triangle inequality instead of Rouché’s theorem also in cases where the function is not a polynomial?

Comment: @Aphelli What product should we consider?